# On simple prime numbers inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_{n}$ denotes the $n$-th prime number.

How can one show that $p_{n+2}>3n$ for all $n\geq 1 ?$

Comment: All primes larger than $3$ have the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$, so there cannot be more than two primes in each set of six consecutive numbers starting after $3$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show this by induction on $n$.

For $n=1$ we can verify that $p_3=5>3\cdot1$
Suppose that the statement holds true for $n$ meaning that $p_{n+2}>3n$. We will show that
this holds for $n+1$.
 We have $p_{(n+1)+2}=p_{n+3}$. We already know from the induction step that $p_{n+2}>3n$ ,so if $p_{n+3}\leq 3(n+1)=3n+3$ we have only one  possibility: $p_{n+3}=3n+2$

> (or $p_{n+3}=3n+1$ which means that $p_{n+2}$ and $p_{n+3}$ coincide .
>   Also, if $p>3$ then $p$ cannot be  a multiple of $3$ so the case
>   $p_{n+3}=3(n+1)$ is rejected)

But this means that $p_{n+2}$ and $p_{n+3}$ are consecutive primes which is only possible if the primes are $2,3$ (we are already above $5$)
All at the above step arrive at a contradiction and so we must have only one possibility: $p_{n+3}>3(n+1)$

this proves the case for $n+1$ and so, for every $n$.